# How to create a custom lookup for custom object in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

I have to create a form where I have many lookup fields
And there is one scenario where when I select an account from Account lookup the contact field should get autopopulated to the contact of that account.
I am not finding the custom lookup code anywhere.
[image]
[image]
Here's the html code

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h2 slot="title">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" size="small"></lightning-icon> 
             <strong class="custom-class">Stock Receiving</strong>
        </h2>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Stock_Recieving__c">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col slds-m-left_small">
                    <label for="vendorid"><div class="required-field">Vendor</div></label>
                    <lightning-input-field icon-name="standard:account" id="vendorid" variant="label-hidden" field-name="Vendor__c" required> </lightning-input-field>  
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <label for="contactid">Contact</label>
                    <lightning-input-field id="contactid" variant="label-hidden" field-name="Contact__c"></lightning-input-field>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <label for="cmpyid"><div class="required-field">Company</div></label>
                    <lightning-input-field id="cmpyid"  variant="label-hidden" field-name="Company__c" required> </lightning-input-field>  
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-m-right_small">
                    <label for="walocid"><div class="required-field">Warehouse Location</div></label>
                    <lightning-input-field id="walocid" variant="label-hidden" field-name="Location__c" required> </lightning-input-field>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col slds-m-left_small">
                    <label for="rcdt"><div class="required-field">Receiving Date Time</div></label>
                    <lightning-input-field id="rdtid" variant="label-hidden" field-name="Received_Date_Time__c" required></lightning-input-field>  
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <label for="delnoid">Delivery Note Number</label>
                    <lightning-input-field id="delnoid" variant="label-hidden" field-name="Delivery_Note_Number__c"></lightning-input-field>  
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-m-right_small">
                    <label for="notesid">Notes</label>
                    <lightning-input-field id="notesid"  variant="label-hidden" field-name="Notes__c"></lightning-input-field>  
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
                <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
                    <span class="slds-truncate slds-p-horizontal_small" title="Stock Receiving Items">Stock Receiving Items</span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <template if:true ={isClicked}>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_8-of-12 slds-large-size_5-of-12">
                    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-top_xx-small slds-col">
                        <lightning-button label="Remove" icon-name="utility:close" icon-position="left"></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-6 slds-medium-size_8-of-12 slds-large-size_8-of-12">
                        <label for="transcid">Select Transactions</label>
                        <lightning-input-field id="transcid" variant="label-hidden" field-name="Purchase_Order__c" onchange={handleAccountSelection}></lightning-input-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <table class="slds-table slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal slds-table_bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table-title">
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate slds-p-left_small" title="Serial Number">
                                    SL. NO.
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Product">
                                    PRODUCT
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Ordered QTY">
                                    ORDERED QTY
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Remaining QTY">
                                    REMAINING QTY
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate required-field" title="Receiving QTY">
                                    RECEIVING QTY
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate required-field" title="Status">
                                    STATUS
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate required-field" title="Bin">
                                    BIN
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Batch No">
                                    BATCH NO.
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Expiry Date">
                                    EXPIRY DATE
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </template>
            <br>
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-m-left_small">
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Add more transactions" onclick={handleTransactions}></lightning-button>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <lightning-button  variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick={closeQuickAction}> </lightning-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: what exactly what you want means you want to populate contact in custom lookup or you want to show related contact in suggestion?

Comment: If there's only one contact related to that account then that contact needs to be populated or if there are more than 1 contacts for that particular account then show the related contacts

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this git code

> https://github.com/karykaran/CustomLookUp

You need to call this component as :

```
<c-lookup object-api-name="User" label="Search User" onrecordupdated={handleUserChange} filters={filterType}>
</c-lookup>
```

Need to define filter in JS like :

```
filterType = {
    'AccountId':['001....']
};
```

If you are getting only 1 value then populate that field automatically and if its more then one then it will show in suggestions like normal lookup

Comment: I used the custom lookup from https://www.forcetree.com/2020/06/custom-lookup-component-in-lwc.html I have to put the filter for Account as Account_Type__c = 'Vendor' I don't know where can I do that?

Comment: And when I used your custom lookup the filter was working but I don't know how to put the red asterisk in the label attribute of c-custom-lookup

Comment: Can you show me how you pass filter in apex from JS. (parameter values?)

Comment: You can check the whole code here www.github.com/iamlavanya123/stockReceiving/tree/main